# How does C language initialise the struct pointer

Tags: c

I am newer to C language. Let's get started with the  test code below.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
int main() {
    struct node *n;
    struct node *n2;
    struct node *n3;
    struct node *n4;
    struct node *n5;
    printf("%p\n", n);
    printf("%p\n", n2);
    printf("%p\n", n3);
    printf("%p\n", n4);
    printf("%p\n", n5);
    return 0;
}
```

The output show below,

```
0x7fff57c42888
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
```

I cannot understand that the pointer address of variable n is not null. And, The other variables that have the same *node type are 0X0.
Who can explain the reason for it? Thx.

Comment: The code invokes **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Variables local to a function are **not** zero-initialized in `c`. You have to do proper initialization yourself. BTW - when printing a pointer value, you shall cast to `(void*)` like `printf("%p\n", (void*)n5);`

Comment: @n.m.: No attempt to use any of the pointers in order to access memory. Why undefined behavior?

Comment: @barakmanos use of uninitialized pointer value - I guess that is UB (note - there is no `&` in the print)

Comment: @barakmanos because that's what the standard says. As much as looking at an unitialized pointer is UB. Just copy one, bang! UB. No need to dereference at all.

Comment: @4386427: So what? You're only printing the (junk) value of the pointer. It doesn't have to point to a valid (properly allocated) memory block. Same as `int n;` followed by `printf("%d",n);`.

Comment: @barakmanos - Your `int` example is UB as well, AFAIK. As I recall it the only uninitialized variable type that you may read without UB is `unsigned char`.

Comment: Thx for your reply, Can I think that using any unsigned type variables will not invokes undefined behaviour, because Unsigned types have rarely trap representations. I referred to [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c)

Comment: If I declare struct node n, will the n variable be automatic initialized? In my test, the n variable was initialized without my explicit declaration in program.

Comment: Then I do a small test. the code as follows,
`void test() {
 struct node n;
 printf("%p\n", &n);
}
int main() {
 test();
 test();
 test();
 test();
}` 
the output show below,
0x7fff537ac840
0x7fff537ac840
0x7fff537ac840
0x7fff537ac840
I cannot understand that every time calling test() prints the same address.

Answer (score 2):

You simply print out the values of non-initialised pointers (`n`, .., `n5`). So there is no guarantee of the output.

Just like you print out an `int` variable without initialising it:

```
int i;
printf( "%d", i ); // what would you expect? - no guarantee, maybe 0, maybe 7
```